# Как конкатенировать числа в с++

Tags: c++, база-данных

Как конкатенировать числа в с++

Comment: Конкатенировать можно строки. А числа можно складывать.

Comment: @KoVadim, говорят же все "написать бота" вместо "написать бот". Хотя "сделать чемодана" почему-то не говорят. Русский совсем испорчен. Так что конкатенацией чисел можно назвать операцию: `123 конк 456 = 123456`

Comment: а почему "написать бота" это неверно. бот происходит от слова робот, а его склонение очень хорошо изучено.  но вот с кофе нужно что то делать, а то метро и пальто уже ждут своей очереди.

Comment: умножаете первое число на 1е<количество десятичных знаков во втором числе>, прибавляете второе число.

Comment: да, и так можно, осталось только понять, причем здесь базы данных и в каком виде нужен результат.

Comment: Если результат должен быть на печати (в файле), то самый простой способ это вывести их подряд, без разделителей

Answer (score 2):

извиняюсь за именно ответ, комментарий по рангу написать не могу. К сути, вы можете переводить числа в строки и уже строки конк. и если нужно то обратно переводить в число. Не самый дешёвый вариант по ресурсам. Но рабочий)

код:

```
#include <string>

void con(int& a, int& b, std::string& result) {
    
    result = (std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b));
    // или можно использовать
    // std::atoi(result.c_str()); это переобразовывает строку в число
}
```

вызов функции

```
int a = 123;
int b = 456;

std::string r;

con(a, b, r);

std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

я проверил на всякий всякий и всё работает

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: напишите пример использование в коде, раз вы ответ написали

Comment: для float не сработает, возможно стоит сделать шаблонную функцию

Comment: но к сожалению для float или double не подойдет данный способ, ведь дробь будет складыватся так 123.321 + 456.654 = 123.321456.654 Так что этот способ подходит только для целых чисел

Comment: С таких соображений тогда наверное и отрицательное второе число стоит запретить.

Comment: Непонятно почему `a`,`b` передаются по ссылке. Из-за этого `con(1, 2, r);` не собирается.

Comment: можно убрать амперсанты

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос в получении именно числа, то

```
unsigned long long concat(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {

    unsigned long long r = a;

    if (!b) return r * 10;

    for (unsigned int c = b; c; c /= 10) r *= 10;

    return r + b;
    }
```